# How to check that user came to the route or url using back button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to do some functionality especially when the user come back to already visited page(history).How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can know for sure that a user pushed the `back` button.

But you can keep a list of visited routes and check if the user has been to that route.

You can use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to store the visited routes, by adding a mutation to push new routes to it.

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    visitedRoutes: [
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
     ADD_VISITED_PAGE (state, route) {
      // mutate state
      state.visitedRoutes.push(route)
    }
  }
})
```

And add a [global after hook](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks) to trigger your mutation

```
router.afterEach( (to, from) => {
  store.commit('ADD_VISITED_PAGE', from)
})
```

After that you can check in your components if a user has visited that page or not.

```
mounted () {
 if (this.$store.state.visitedRoutes.contains(this.$route.name)) {
   // you've been here before
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your router is not configured in history mode because from vue router docs "history mode, which leverages the history.pushState API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload" ,
You can hook into vue router event to save the previous url

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    previousRoutes.push(from)
    next()
})
```

More information here https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html
Now you can check to see, if the user came back, if the route is already present in previousRoutes - to an already visited page.